# How to interact with docker swarm to change the strategy in scheduler

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

When docker swarm was released in both, standalone and swarm mode, one of the main features was the possibility to change scheduler between binpack and spread. If I run docker swarm in docker-machine, I can choose the strategy by passing the `--swarm-strategy` parameter, but if I try it running in swarm mode there is in CLI command to pass that parameter.

I found some issues in the docker repository on github that people ask about new strategies different of binpack and spread, but, again, I didnt find how to change it. Seeing the docker source code in master branch, again, there is no CLI command to interact with these parameters.

I know how to interact with docker though docker-machine and standalone to send these parameters, but I don't know that using docker swarm mode. My question is: How to change the strategies when using docker swarm mode? Or: When it will be possible?

Comment: Have you found some solution?

Comment: As of Docker version 17.06.0, according to the README on Swarm Kit repo in Github (https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/blob/766c68f98957013be854cba423bcb36c1b17802e/README.md), only available option is Spread.

Have you tried testing the swarm cluster created with binpack or random? Looking at the docker/machine repo, they seem to be inactive too.